# Jquery forming malformed URL on JSON AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm making a JSON-P request to an API via jQuery AJAX

```
$('#fetch').click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                url: 'http://abettertms.com/api2/terms',
                dataType: 'jsonp',                                
                success: function(){
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function() { console.log('error'); }
            });
        });
```

Debugging using the Chrome console shows the ajax request is made to

```
http://abettertms.com/api2/terms?callback=jQuery1710946886689402163_1328157759295&_=1328157761647
```

with the extra parameter `&_=1328157761647`. Why is jQuery adding that? The API I'm calling is my own, so in a crunch I can edit the API to ignore the extraneous parameter, but I'd prefer not having to resort to that.

Comment: I guess thats the timestamp jQuery is adding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cache**
Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'

If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL. 
See cache param in following link.

Ref: [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: what if u didnt want to cache but wanted to remove the timestamp due to IE8 URL Character limit?

Answer (score 1):

It's adding that to prevent the browser from caching those responses. It's probably a timestamp value, generated to be different every time you make that jsonp call. Why is in the way? Maybe there are alternatives to whatever your problem is.

See if it goes away if you add `cache:true` as an argument to `$.ajax` call.

Comment: I set up the API so that in the case of any extraneous and unexpected GET parameters, I respond with a HTTP 400 Bad Request

Comment: BTW, ignoring query args is perfectly ok, all websites do it, and you're achieving very little (if not the opposite) by throwing errors when unexpected query arg is found (if you're preventing abuse of your service, you're only helping those probing it to guess what ISN'T relevant). Besides, you can put `"_"` of type `int64` on your "approved" list.